# How to make image disappear with a smaller page size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a design for a website and when you decrease the size of the page I want a specific image in the footer to disappear.

Is this even possible?

Comment: lookup CSS Media queries

Comment: maybe helpfull http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is easily doable.  I suggest you use [CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to get the job done.

```
/* Normal CSS rules (always applies) */
#footer { display: none; }

/* Media query rules to override previous rules, as necessary */
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { 
   #footer { display: block; } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not only possible, but fairly simple with media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    .myImageClass {display:none;}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done either with CSS Media Queries or using Javascript. SmashingMagazine has a good article that can help you get started: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/